# Vue JS Main.js failed to compile

Tags: vue.js

Keep getting this error. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling node and vue but does not seem to work

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                               7:03:46 PM
>
> error  in ./src/main.js

main.js code below:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: What is the error? The code you show doesn't seem to have anything wrong per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eslint, try removing comma.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),   //please remove the comma
    }).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Good advice but a trailing comma will not fail compilation (I just checked)

Comment: What do you think is the cause of this problem? I can't find a problem with this question.

Comment: Won't know until OP provides an actual error message

Comment: I'm not sure. It happens every time I create a project